# What are the differences between JWT and OAuth authentication?

Tags: oauth, jwt

What are the main differences between JWT and OAuth authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth is typically used to request permission of a user, where as JWT is most often used for server to server communication.  To grant once system access to another system.  So no user is required to authorize the call.

A JWT is composed of three parts: a header, a claim set, and a signature.

> {Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}

All information needed by the application to access the system would be imbedded with in this.   I am currently using this to access patient medical data on behalf of a medical provider.  The patient doesn't need to grant me access because I have been granted access by the medical provider in the form of a certificate that allows me to generate the JWT for each patient granting me access to their data.  I just need to imbed the patients system number in order to have access.

With Oauth2 a user must grant consent by being shown a consent screen the authorization server will then return an access token and refresh token which will grant access to the users data.